# question about finer topology

Tags: general-topology, compactness

‎‎A topological space $X$ is said to be **star compact** if whenever $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $X$, there is a compact subspace $K$ of $X$ such that $X = \mathrm{st}(K,\mathscr{U}),$ where
$\mathrm{st}(K, \mathscr{U})
= \bigcup \{ U \in \mathscr{U}: U \cap K \neq \emptyset \}.$

We recursively define $\mathrm{st}^n$ for $n=0,1,2,\ldots$ by
$$\begin{align}
\mathrm{st}^0(K, \mathscr{U})
&= K
\\
\mathrm{st}^{n+1}(K, \mathscr{U}‎)
&= \bigcup ‎\{ U‎ ‎\in‎ \mathscr{‎U} : U ‎\cap\  \mathrm{st}^n(K, \mathscr{U}‎) \neq ‎\emptyset \}‎‎‎
\end{align}$$

**Definition:** ‎A space $X$ is said to be ‎$ ‎\omega‎$‎-starcompact if for every open cover ‎$\mathscr{U}‎$‎ of ‎‎$X$‎, there is some ‎‎$‎n ‎\in ‎\mathbb{N‎}‎‎^{+}‎$‎ and some finite subset ‎‎$B$‎ of ‎‎$X$‎ such that ‎‎$\mathrm{st}^{‎n‎}(B, \mathscr{U}) = X‎$‎.‎‎
‎

> Let‎‎ ‎$(X, ‎\tau)$ be‎ $\omega‎$‎-‎starcompact and $\tau^{*} \subset \tau$. Is $(X, \tau^{*})$ a‎ $‎\omega‎ $‎-‎starcompact ‎space?‎

Comment: Are $St$ and $st$ supposed to be the same? What is the base case in the recursive definition of $st^{n+1}$? Is $st^1 = St$?

Comment: I made an edit, primarily to fix some rendering errors. I found that there were a lot of [Unicode left-to-right marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) in the text. Removing them helped. Secondarily, in the edit I also fixed (I hope) the definition of $\mathrm{st}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think so!

To see this, fix $\mathscr{U} \subseteq \tau^* \subseteq \tau $, an open cover of $X$, and pick a finite set $B \subseteq X$ and whole number $n$ for which $st^n(B,\mathscr{U}) = X$.

Note $st(B,\mathscr{U})$ is the same open set (i.e. the same union of open sets from the open cover) regardless of which topology we consider.  In fact, for all $k$, $st^k(B,\mathscr{U})$ is the same union of open sets from the open cover regardless of which topology we consider.  As such, $st^n(B,\mathscr{U}) = X$, regardless of which topology we consider.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, every $\tau^\ast$-open cover is a $\tau$-open cover and we have $B$ there which still works. Many simple covering properties are preserved by going to a coarser topology, like (countable) compactness and Lindelöfness.